# How to use Yeoman with Express/Jade/Stylus?

Tags: express, pug, stylus, yeoman

I recently found out about Yeoman and found it can be very useful in improving workflow. However, I noticed it seem to focus only on client side projects? ExpressJS is a popular framework that seems to be been missed out?

However, I still think its possible to integrate it into Yeoman, perhaps with custom generators? Is there something like that already available? If not how might I start?

It will not be as simple, along with Express, I will be using Jade/Stylus the defaults express uses for precompiling HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial goal of Yeoman was to tackle front-end web apps.

Opinionated workflow with the back-end is [planned](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/625), but is currently a bit [cumbersome to do](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/809). Use of Jade/Styles is [possible](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Stylus-integration), but a bit ugly.

All this will be much easier with Yeoman 1.0, which will be more customizable and will let you use whatever grunt tasks you want.