# using stylus in yeoman

Tags: backbone.js, gruntjs, yeoman, stylus

I want to use stylus in a yeoman project

I'm following the instructions here 
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Stylus-integration

From this SO question
[How to use Yeoman with Express/Jade/Stylus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067436/how-to-use-yeoman-with-express-jade-stylus)

But it's not working. I'm using Yeoman v1.0.5 - is this documentation out of date? Or maybe I'm just being stupid...

I'm using it in an app generated by genetator-backbone if that makes any difference. It talks about removing the compass bits, but they aren't there. Perhaps there's something in that?

Answer (score 0):

My fault. Because I was adding stylus from scratch and not overriding compass, I needed to reference my stylus action in the various grunt.registerTask() calls.